# Entering Date in Excel Sheet in VB. Date format changes if day is entered less than 12

Tags: vb.net

This is my Code :

```
'HomeP form has the excelapp, excelwb, excelws objects initialized.

HomeP.excelws.Range("C1", "C900000").NumberFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
HomeP.excelws.Range("D1", "D900000").NumberFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
```

I'm taking input using a textbox.

```
HomeP.excelws.Cells(2, 3).Value = TextBox3.Text
HomeP.excelws.Cells(2, 4).Value = TextBox4.Text
```

[EDIT] : Now the issue is, if I enter '23-12-2001' then it will store as '23-Dec-2001' in excel but if I enter '01-11-2001' then it will store it as '11-Jan-2001'. I don't think it's about the input but how Excel interprets it when the day is less than 12. My system date format is dd-mm-yyyy. I want to have date format in excel cell as 'dd-MMM-yyyy'

Comment: PS - I'm using MS Excel 2010 and Visual Studio 2015 for Coding.

Comment: If the value represented by `TextBox3.Text` is supposed to be  a `DateTime`, then parse that string to a  `DateTime` variable and assign that variable to the `Excel.Range.Value` property.  Doing so removes all ambiguities.

Comment: Tried it. Still no success. Check out the comment in the answer below. :)

Comment: `Tried it. Still no success.` --> `Dim timee As DateTime = TextBox3.Text Dim Formatt As String = "dd-MM-yyyy" Dim newdate = timee.ToString(Formatt) HomeP.excelws.Cells(2, 3).Value = newdate`.  That is not what I suggested.  You are still assigning a String.  Try: `HomeP.excelws.Cells(2, 3).Value = CDate(TextBox3.Text)`

Comment: Thank You so much. That worked for me :) Sorry my bad didn't follow you correctly, newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can try :

```
        Dim Timee As DateTime = HomeP.excelws.Cells(2, 3).Value
        Dim Formatt As String = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        Dim newdate = Timee.ToString(Formatt)
        TextBox3.Text = newdate
```

and please tell me if it work !!

Comment: Dim timee As DateTime = TextBox3.Text
                Dim Formatt As String = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                Dim newdate = timee.ToString(Formatt)
                HomeP.excelws.Cells(2, 3).Value = newdate
Tried this, still the same. 
I think the problem is not about the input but how excel interprets it. It automatically changes the format when the entered day is less than 12. It does not change the date format from dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy. It interprets it in a different way. For eg. I entered 01/12/2017, it  was saved in excel as 12-Jan-2017.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to TnTinMin and Aladein, The problem has been solved. I've created this method to get the date in my required format.

```
    Public Function GetDateProperly(ByVal tb As TextBox)
    Try
        Dim timee As DateTime = tb.Text
        Dim Formatt As String = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        Dim newdate = timee.ToString(Formatt)
        Return CDate(newdate)
    Catch ex As System.InvalidCastException
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
    End Try
    End Function
```